Debian 12 issue with Dell Precision 3581 and Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2
I am running Debian 12 on my Dell Precision 3581. I typically go between two physical locations, both of which have docking stations. One docking station, a Dell something or other, always works flawlessly. The other, a Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2, works great when I boot my laptop with the docking station connected, but I have USB issues when I undock and re-dock.
Here's is lsusb | sort after a boot while docked
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:28d2 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_FHD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. AX211 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 17ef:3080 Lenovo USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2109:2820 VIA Labs, Inc. VL820 Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2109:8818 VIA Labs, Inc. USB Billboard Device   
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 17ef:3081 Lenovo USB2.0 HUB
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 17ef:3083 Lenovo ThinkPad Thunderbolt 3 Dock USB Audio
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 17ef:608d Lenovo Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 17ef:307f Lenovo USB3.1 Hub             
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2109:0820 VIA Labs, Inc. VL820 Hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 17ef:3082 Lenovo ThinkPad TBT 3 Dock
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

and this is what I have after undocking and re-docking
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:28d2 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_FHD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. AX211 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

As you can see, buses 3 and 4 are missing. The only log I can find that something is going wrong is in dmesg which shows
[  688.046933] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Host halt failed, -19                                                                                                                                                          
[  688.046942] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.                     
[  688.047612] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered   

I did a few more sanity checks (lsmod, tree /sys/bus/usb/drivers/, ls -al /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd which I can post here if desired) which again confirm that the USB buses and and corresponding PCI devices are missing, I can't find the reason why. Does anyone have any ideas?
